# GNU Linker differences between the different 32bit emulation modes?

Tags: x86, linker, ld

What is the difference between the 386 and 32 bit options in `ld -V`?

- `elf32_x86_64`
- `elf_i386`
- `i386linux`
- `i386pep`
- `i386pe`

And, where can I find the documentation on these "emulation modes"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The “emulation” selects different [linker scripts](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Scripts.html); you’ll find the scripts themselves in `/usr/lib/ldscripts` on your system. The emulations you’ve listed correspond to

- `elf32_x86_64`: ELF for x64-32, aka [x32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) — 32-bit x86-64 binaries
- `elf_i386`: ELF for i386 — 32-bit i386 binaries
- `i386linux`: a.out for i386
- `i386pep`: PE+ for x86-64 — Windows-format 64-bit binaries
- `i386pe`: PE for i386 — Windows-format 32-bit binaries

The linker scripts define the output format and architecture, the search directories (where `ld` looks for libraries), the sections in the binary, among other things.

The linker script format is well documented (see above), but the available scripts aren’t; in most cases GCC will specify the right one, so you don’t need to worry about it, and in other cases you effectively end up needing to read the linker scripts themselves to figure out what they do.

Comment: Extra info: x32 is a 32bit executable format, that will only run on x86_64. It is intended to use the benefits of x86 64bit mode, but be smaller than 64bit code. All data types (except time), are same as in 32bit mode.

Comment: What's  'a.out for i386' ?

Comment: There's another format `elf_x86_64` in the `ld -V` output. I believe it is the same thing as the `elf64-x86-64` in the `objdump -i` ouput. Both should mean the 64-bit x86-64 binaries. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the `ldscripts/` information, very useful! However it's not the end of the story. If/when you provide your own linker script like I did then ldscripts/ are ignored, you can move them out and everything still works. Yet even with all ldscripts/ gone (for testing `ld`), I found there was still a difference between `-melf_i386` and `-melf_x86_64`! Alignment. The ELF output of the former was aligned to be mmapped on 4K pages and the latter on 2M pages. This was with `ld.bfd` 2.32.

Comment: If you can't find `ldscripts/` on your system, they're probably built in the executable. You can extract them like this: `ld --verbose > default.xc`, `ld --verbose --melf_x86_64 --nmagic > elf_x86_64.xn`, etc.